# error in buildespec file of aws codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, cicd

I am creating a pipeline using codepipeline in aws. I have a simple react node application. I am trying to implement cicd using aws codepipeline.
In the codebuild part, I mentioned everything like the github part but I am having problem with the buildspec file. I don't know what is wrong or I am doing it incorrectly.

I am getting error *"no such file or directory, open '/codebuild/output/src1238056502/src/github.com/zainabmirkar/react-node-cicdproject/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file."*

I tried to read documentation but nothing is specified about this problem. I also read some blogs and implemented the things that they have mentioned but still nothing.

this is my buildspec:
[buildspec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kFOj.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because codebuild is unable to find a `package.json` file in the root folder of your project. Make sure it exists there and not in some subdirectory.